# Is there a way to specify multiple Decoders (or one per Topic) in a Kafka Consumer? Anyone else felt need for this?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am doing Spark Streaming over Kafka work in Scala ([ref](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/streaming-kafka-integration.html)) using

```
public static <K,V,U extends kafka.serializer.Decoder<?>,T extends kafka.serializer.Decoder<?>> ReceiverInputDStream<scala.Tuple2<K,V>> createStream(StreamingContext ssc, scala.collection.immutable.Map<String,String> kafkaParams, scala.collection.immutable.Map<String,Object> topics, StorageLevel storageLevel, scala.reflect.ClassTag<K> evidence$1, scala.reflect.ClassTag<V> evidence$2, scala.reflect.ClassTag<U> evidence$3, scala.reflect.ClassTag<T> evidence$4)
```

I want to receive different types of messages (that need different Decoders) in the same `DStream` and the underlying `RDD` every batch interval. I will be listening to multiple topics and each topic will correspond to one message type thereby needing its own `Decoder`. Currently it does not seem like there's away to provide a `kafka.serializer.Decoder<?>` per topic (Is there one?). It seems fairly likely that people would send different type of messages over each topic (`protobuf` serialized bytes?). Has anyone else run into this issue?

Thanks.

C.

It seems a mapping of `topic` to `valueDecoder`somewhere in [here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/consumer/ConsumerIterator.scala) could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you need two DStream, one per topic. Then you will be able to perform join or union to get a single dstream with all elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use the createDirectStream api, which gives you access to the topic on a per-partition basis via HasOffsetRanges. For the kafka decoder use the DefaultDecoder to get an array of bytes for each message.

Then do your actual decoding in a mapPartitions, where you match against the topic name to figure out how to interpret the array of bytes.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html